# A non-empty request body is required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've found a few other questions here on SO that address this issue; however, all those questions seem to have had their issues in the type of request being sent wether content-type was the issue, or model binding. In my situation, the error seems to get thrown on the `Ok` at the end of the action method.

So far I have have tried the following:

- Adding/removing `FromBody` attribute
- Ensuring my testing framework *Swagger* is sending as `application/json`
- I tried changing to to a `Patch` just to see what would happen but the issue still persists
- I also tried changing the return from `Ok` to `NoContent` and the issue still persists

As I said above, I did step through this code and verified that I hit the mapping code and all properties are properly mapped. The user itself does get updated in the database. The error is only thrown after execution exits the action method (after `Ok`) is called. So this throws me off even more since the error insists my request body is empty.

**Are there any other reasons this error would be thrown besides an actual empty request body or wrong content-type payload?**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the provided account and setting information
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vm"></param>
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400, Type=typeof(string))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAccountInfo([FromBody]UpdateAccountInfoViewModel vm)
    {
        var appModel = _mapper.Map<ChartLog.Application.Models.UpdateAccountInfoModel>(vm);
        appModel.UserId = User.GetUserId().Value;

        await _accountApp.UpdateAccountAndSettings(appModel);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem ended up being with a bug in a custom middleware I created. I was replaying the request twice.

```
  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        string stringBody = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            await next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (context.Request.Body.CanSeek)
            {
                stringBody = await FormatRequest(context.Request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, stringBody).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        //await next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The commented out code was the culprit. If no exception occurred then it would exit the try and essentially replay the same `RequestDelegate`. My assumption is the request stream has already been read and is already disposed or read to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue when I try to learn HttpPath. And I found the root cause is: I didn't pass the "Content-Length" value in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the issue on sending data to Swagger Api. When Swagger is sending as application/json it is needed to support the data just in raw json format in body.
As the Content-Type is JSON, sending data as parameters in URL  will return the response:

> A non-empty request body is required

And if the data is placed in body with Form format this is leaded to this response :

> "'-' is invalid within a number, immediately after a sign character ('+' or '-'). Expected a digit ('0'-'9'). Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."

Put the data in raw json to resolve the issue.

> {
> "username": "abcd",
> "password": "123456"
> }

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but I just ran into this error and traced it to another cause that has not been mentioned yet. In my case, the deserialization of the body was failing due to case-sensitivity and/or naming conventions, and I got that rather unhelpful error message. I found that it worked fine if I ensured that all the property names in the JSON were lowercase, but not otherwise. Your mileage may vary, but for me the fix was to add this to my startup:

```
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;             
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was how I was sending the parameters. So my final code looks like;

My controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[ApiController]
public class MyApiController : BaseApiController
{
    public void Post(TestObject value)
    {
    }
}
```

My http call:

```
var _post = function (data) {
    var requestJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
    var _defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://" + window.location.host + "/api/MyApi/",
        data: requestJSON,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    })
        .then(function (result) {
            _defer.resolve(result.data);
        },
    function () { _defer.reject(); });
        return _defer.promise;
    };
```

And how I build my parameter:

```
    $scope.save = function () {

        var parameters = new Object();
        parameters.Id = 1;
        parameters.Name = 'Juan Perez';

        app.POST(parameters).then(function () {
            console.log('ok');
        }, function (data) {
            console.log('error');
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a **mismatch between the calling client and the parameters on the server** method (some refactoring work hadn't made it through version control, and hence deployed to the server).

Previous refactored out client call

```
this.http.put<string>(environment.apiHost + 
              '/api/LifeFabricBranch/SaveLifeFabricBranchBulkMediaUpload? 
              uploadBatchId=' +  this.uploadBatch?.id
              + '&privacyLevelId=' + this.lifeFabricBranch.privacyLevelId,         
              payload)
```

Notice the **payload http body** here

New client call after refactoring work

```
this.http.put<string>(environment.apiHost + 
              '/api/LifeFabricBranch/SaveLifeFabricBranchBulkMediaUpload? 
              uploadBatchId=' +  this.uploadBatch?.id
              + '&privacyLevelId=' + this.lifeFabricBranch.privacyLevelId
              + '&lifeFabricBranchId=' + this.lifeFabricBranch.id,         
              null)
```

Notice that the **http body is null** here, and I am just using querystring parameters

Now the sever method was still still stuck at an older version

```
[Authorize]
[Route("SaveLifeFabricBranchBulkMediaUpload")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveLifeFabricBranchBulkMediaUpload(
  Guid uploadBatchId, 
  int privacyLevelId, 
  [FromBody] LifeFabricBranchDto lifeFabricBranch)
                {
```

Notice the **third parameter is expecting something in the HTTP body** as part of the put request, but in the newer version of the client, **I am just passing a querystring parameter** here.

Updating the server correctly made the bug "go away"

```
[Authorize]
[Route("SaveLifeFabricBranchBulkMediaUpload")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveLifeFabricBranchBulkMediaUpload(
  Guid uploadBatchId, 
  int privacyLevelId, 
  Guid lifeFabricBranchId)
        {
```